# Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS does not start desktop

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, login

I have never worked with Linux before. However, I was able to work with my new Ubuntu computer until I was prompted to update from 12.02 to 12.04, which I did.

Immediately after rebooting, I got to the black screen asking for my username and password. It does not do anything else: it always displays a message saying "No irq handler for vector (irq -1)". No matter what I do it always end up by displaying that message. I really don't know how to start my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Is it displaying " No irq handler for vector (irq -1) " after you entered your username and password? Do you get a username@machinename:~$ prompt after that message? If so, try to enter this command:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

After it prompts for password, enter your password.